# Change images Timeout Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, loops, timeout, alternate

I have two images, green and black. I want to alternate those images in a certain frequency. 
My code:

```
<script>
var wis=1;
var delay=500;
wissel()
function wissel() {
if (wis==1) 
    {wis=2; green();}
else {wis=1; black();}
delay=delay+500;
setTimeout (wissel(), delay)
}

function green() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(438,398,125,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.arc(838,398,125,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="#00ff00";
ctx.fill();
}
function black() {
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(438,398,128,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.arc(838,398,128,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
ctx.fill();
}
</script>
```

When I insert an alert(wis) behind the delay=delay+500; line it works. But of course I do not want to click. I want it automatically. I can use some help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your `setTimeout` call. Remove the parentheses:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/kk4az/)

```
var wis = 1;
var delay = 500;
wissel()

function wissel() {
    if (wis == 1) {
        wis = 2;
        green();
    } else {
        wis = 1;
        black();
    }
    delay = delay + 500;
    setTimeout(wissel, delay)
}

function green() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(438, 398, 125, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.arc(838, 398, 125, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
    ctx.fill();
}

function black() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(438, 398, 128, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.arc(838, 398, 128, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
}
```